# Increasing sequence of positive operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Denote the set $\mathcal C:=\{x\in\mathbf A:0\leq x\leq p\}$ where $\mathbf A$ is $C^*$ algebra and $p$ is a projection. How to show that every chain in $\mathcal C$ has a maximal element? Actually, I need to use Zorn's lemma in some other context but this where the case reduces to.

Comment: You can't guarantee the existence of a maximal element, as for any chain with a maximal element that is not a successor (such examples can easily be constructed in this context), you can remove the maximal element, and obtain a chain without a maximal element.  Do you mean you want every chain to be bounded above? In this case, if you intend to apply Zorn's lemma, the maximal element you will obtain is $p$.

Comment: @Aweygan what you say is of course correct, but you don't need Zorn or anything to show that every chain is bounded from above. Its basically the main part of the definition that $\mathcal C$ has a maximal element!

Comment: @s.harp Of course.  Maybe my wording was confusing,  I'm not saying we need Zorn's lemma to see that $p$ is a maximal element of $\mathcal C$.  I intended to say that using Zorn's lemma is not necessary, because, as you say, by definition $p$ is a (and moreover the unique) maximal element of $\mathcal C$.